# PHP - How to create a secure 10 digits key

Tags: php, random, key

Well, i need a way to create a random unique key of 10 digits that matchs to the follow pattern:

LLNNNLLNNN

where **L** is a letter and **N** is a number.

I have found a solution but i'm looking for some smart opinion.
My solution was (php):

```
        $alhpabet = ['A','B','C','D','E','F','G','H','I','J','K','L','M','N','O','P','Q','R','S','T','U','V','X','W','Y','Z']; //26 letras         
        $transaction_id = ''; //string

        //Two first letters
        $transaction_id .= $alhpabet[secure_random_number(0,25)];
        $transaction_id .= $alhpabet[secure_random_number(0, 26)];
        //3 first numbers (3 digits)
        $transaction_id .= str_pad(secure_random_number(0, 999),3,'0',STR_PAD_LEFT);
        //last letters
        $transaction_id .= $alhpabet[secure_random_number(0,25)];
        $transaction_id .= $alhpabet[secure_random_number(0, 26)];
        //last numbers
        $transaction_id .= str_pad(secure_random_number(0, 999),3,'0',STR_PAD_LEFT);
```

My function to generate secure_random_number is:

```
function secure_random_number($min, $max){
$range = $max - $min;
if($range == 0)
    return $min; // not so random...
$log = log($range, 2);
$bytes = (int) ($log / 8) + 1; // length in bytes
$bits = (int) $log + 1; // length in bits
$filter = (int) (1 << $bits) - 1; // set all lower bits to 1
do{
    $rnd = hexdec(bin2hex(openssl_random_pseudo_bytes($bytes, $s)));
    $rnd = $rnd & $filter; // discard irrelevant bits
}while($rnd >= $range);
return $min + $rnd;
}
```

ps: i get this somewhere in here, but forget to note the credits...

**NOTE:** I'm not worried about performance.

Comment: If you have a problem with this code, please state it clearly in the question. If this code works, and you simply want to improve it, your question might be better suited for: http://codereview.stackexchange.com

Comment: How can i change it to codereview.stackexchange.com?!

Comment: You can delete your question and re-post it over there, or wait and a moderator might eventually migrate it for you.

Comment: Under those constraints, there are only 456,976,000,000 possible values. That's far too small for any random process to avoid collisions in a database of any size.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As a general rule of thumb, key collisions become likely when the number of samples (database items) approaches the square root of the total number of keys. Think of the birthday problem: even a room of only 23 people will have two with the same birthday 50% of the time, because 23 > sqrt(365.25).

Your key scheme has only 456,976,000,000 values (26 ** 4 * 10 ** 6). Sqrt of that is 676,000. That means even with only half a million or so items in your database, you are likely to have collisions. How you choose them is totally irrelevant.

Answer (score 1):

Always a sucker for algorithms. Here's a recursive generalized variant you might fancy:

```
function gencode($pattern) {
  if ($key = substr($pattern, 0, 1)) {
      $code = ($key == 'L') ? chr(rand(65, 90)) : rand(0, 9);
      return $code.gencode(substr($pattern, 1));
  } else return null;
}

echo gencode('LLNNNLLNNN');
```

The function gencode will take any pattern of any length and generate a random code according to the pattern of L's and N's.

Comment: Nice, but actually; after testing this myself, will produce an 11-digit sequence. NF1102ML681 (11) - GU788WC2921 (11) being a few numbers generated. OP is asking for a 10-digit sequence.

Comment: The code works, it was actually the print_r routine that tacked on an extra "1" at the end of the output every time. I have amended the code above to use echo instead.

Comment: Ah yes, I had a feeling that would have played a role. Thanks Svea, *cheers*